How to use a negative voltage to switch betwen positive voltage and ground
Basically the title, I want the output to be a positive voltage when the control voltage is negative and the output should either be ground or open when there is no control signal (it is left floating), please help me out thanks.
What I have tried: It works in simulation, the circuit on the left outputs positive voltage and the circuit on the right gives 0 volts, what should I keep in mind when actually building this circuit?


The exact problem is that,I am using a centre tapped battery supply to get dual power supply (i am using two 18650 li-ion batteries in series), and have added a battery protection IC the HY2120, but this IC only opens up the negative rail, so one of the battery will continue to discharge. I want to prevent this.
The batteries will be connected to positive and negative voltage regulators, and these regulators have a shutdown pin in them, the negative regulator gets switched off when the battery protection IC opens the negative rail, but the positive voltage regulator will still be in ON state and one of the battery continue to discharge.
The positive voltage regulator is in ON state when its shutdown pin is HIGH (above 1.2V) and is in OFF/SHUTDOWN state when its shutdown pin is GROUNDED or FLOATING.
The negative voltage regulator is in ON state when its shutdown pin is HIGH (above 1.6V and below -1.9V) and is in OFF/SHUTDOWN state when its shutdown pin is GROUNDED or FLOATING.
I need to turn OFF/SHUTDOWN the positive voltage regulator when the battery protection IC opens the negative rail, how do I achieve this?
Positive regulator: LT1761 https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1761sff.pdf
Negative regulator: LT1964 https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1964fb.pdf

I would just use the opamp, and connect the signal to in-.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Opamps can be very cheap today.
If you insist on using the transistors, you need to use p-channel MOS with Vgs ON more negative than your positive signal (1.2V if i understood correctly). So:

simulate this circuit
When input voltage will be 0V, the voltage over R1 will be -1.2V which will not open the transistor (you have to pick the transistor with significantly negative VgsON = below -1.2V). In this case, the R2 will act as pull-down and voltage on it will be 0V.
When the input will be negative (=-1.9V), the voltage over R1 will be -3.1V, and the transistor will open, causing voltage on R2 to become 1.2V.
